Do programmable NFTs by default enforce royalty? Or do we need to add custom ruleset for that?
How to make sure that royalty is enforced in pNFTs. Do we just mint with ruleset: null because enforcement is implemented by default? Or do we have to explicitly mention any ruleset there?
